# Unable to get the JSON response while I try to consume a service using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, rest

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>REST API With Javascript</h3>
    <button id="connect">Connect</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            function Contact(access_token, instance_url, id, token_type, issued_at, signature) {
                this.access_token = access_token;
                this.instance_url = instance_url;
                this.id = id;
                this.token_type = token_type;
                this.issued_at = issued_at;
                this.signature = signature;

                this.toJsonString = function () { 
                    return JSON.stringify(this); 
                }
            }

            $('#connect').click(function(){  
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token?grant_type=password&client_id=3MVG9ZL0ppGP5UrBcvLyXYRmRUuYKSgFgQayclpZBWmbi7PQ2vWj1V8Xev.GfE0C9xyWMrTzONlj2GZ0ow6VK&client_secret=2150505966475551576&username=manoj6893@gmail.com&password=9989832835j4oKKODMzqViqjJ2ORFEogUokh",
                    data: Contact,
                    dataType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: success_callback,
                    error: error_callback, 
                    dataType: "jsonp"  
                });
            });

            function success_callback(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('fail');
            }

            function error_callback(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                alert('success');
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When i try to hit salesforce.com using oAuth 2.0 in jQuery I am getting following error.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: There's nothing specifically wrong with your code. The 400 error code means that the receiving server doesn't like the data you're sending it. Check both the API documentation to see what it's expecting and the data you're sending.

Comment: If I try to consume the service using apex programming ,it is working fine.But as per my requirement I have to do it in JS/jQuery(clint side programming only).

Comment: I just noticed that you're setting the function reference of `Contact` to the `data` property. Do you instead intend to send an object?

Comment: {"access_token":"00D28000000IzNJ!ARIAQOUTYHr3_fE_oWyhQgdF0i8KaUkxbXH4g.UUXmtSGU7EgV3Stjd3k2nBWUqQeEz_Qm_8b8ASXsTekTL7GsMT9BW2aq_d","instance_url":"https://manoj6893-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com","id":"https://login.salesforce.com/id/00D28000000IzNJEA0/00528000000EERoAAO","token_type":"Bearer","issued_at":"1450783718737","signature":"6vNCpTDMDtzM4L4Z6SyGTyfJYrqtzn5C8k0OlSbed9I="}      ======> this is format I am getting when I hit the service.Please tell me is there any alternative to for Contact property

Comment: try sending `new Contact( .. ).toJsonString()`

Answer (score 0):

Please, Refer link for solution

[Creating a jQuery application using the Force.com REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/08/creating-jquery-application-using-rest-api.html)

Comment: Thanks for your response.But I need to complete it in single page.So that I am using Username-password type.

Comment: when i remove dataType: "jsonp" that gives alert with success but, not any response data.